# About the 2-D array in C++,what is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++

**Description:**

Jack is growing some peanuts in his garden. The garden is a L * W rectangle and every unit  area has its independent number of how much peanuts he will harvest. He wants to find out what the maximum amount of peanuts is in a given-sized region. This region has fixed size as a*b.

**Input Format:**

Line 1 : 2 integer length L and width W

Line 2 - L+1 : W integer per line, representing the amount of peanuts in unit area, A (0<=A<=10）

Line L+2 : 2 integer, a and b, representing the length and width of the selected region

**Output Format:**

One integer m, which is the maximum sum of the amount of peanuts in the selected a*b region

**Sample input:**

```
4 5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 0 0
0 9 2 2 3
3 0 0 0 1
3 3
```

**Sample output**

```
38
```

Data satisfying: 1≤a≤L，1≤b≤W

I think this problem can be abstracted to:
Return the MAXIMUM SUM of numbers in a*b sub-array of a L*W array
I consider there are (L-a+1)*(W-b+1) possible sums and I have to find the maximum.

My code is here, which cannot give the correct result. My code always returns the sum of the upper-left region of the area, but actually the problem need to return the MAXIMUM SUM of the a*b region among all possible positions. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
 
int L,W,a,b,i,j,x,y,p,q,r,s;
 
int main()
{
    cin>>L>>W;
    int peanut[L][W];
    for (i=0;i<L;i++) 
     for (j=0;j<W;j++) 
       cin>>peanut[i][j];
    cin>>a>>b;
 
    int sumArray[L-a+1][W-b+1];
    memset(sumArray,0,(L-a+1)*(W-b+1)*sizeof(int));
     
    for (p=0;p<L-a+1;p++)
     for (q=0;q<W-b+1;q++) 
       {
        for (r=p;r<a;r++)
         for (s=q;s<b;s++) sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[r][s]; 
       }
        
    int max = 0;
    for (x=0;x<L-a+1;x++)
     for (y=0;y<W-b+1;y++) 
       if (sumArray[x][y]>max) max=sumArray[x][y];
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? I just ran it with your example and gave me the right output.

Comment: `int peanut[L][W];` - this is not C++...

Comment: The sub-area is defined only for extent, not for position, I see no way to ask for the middle 3x3 section.

Comment: @Pedrom: This is a GCC extension. It's not C++ indeed.

Comment: OK, first of all: 38 *is* the sum of the values of the upper-left 3x3 area of the array, so maybe you should re-phrase your problem? You say your code returns the sum of the left-uppermost area, but this would seem to be correct - so what is your code *actually* returning? Secondly: variable names - they are probably meaningful to you, but are cryptic to everyone else, and I got a headache just trying to read the code, let alone debug it.

Comment: @kotlomoy Fair enough :) kbok thanks for pointing about the gcc extension

Comment: @Pedrom yes the code will run but it will just give the sum of the a*b region on the left-upper-most. as the problem requires to find out the max from all possible region selections.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so we can have a correct example of the output? I still don't quite understand what is asked

Comment: @FrankXu I can't help you because I have to rewrite your project to compile. Write valid C++ next time.

Comment: @FrankXu it looks like the maximum sum happens to be at the top left. What happens if you make the bottom-right element `100`?

Comment: @Useless Yes, if I make the bottom-right element 100, it still returns 38, so that's my question. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.  First of all, `a` and `b` are the test region's size.

```
     for (r=p;r<a;r++)
       for (s=q;s<b;s++) 
          sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[r][s];
```

Here, `p` and `q` represent initial indecies, however you are checking the index against the subreigion dimension limits.  Instead, it should be:

```
     for (r=p;r<p+a;r++)
       for (s=q;s<q+b;s++) 
          sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[r][s];
```

The second issue is that 38 *is* the answer; the topleft-most region contains the maximum of all the subrectangles.  Here is my solution that prints all of the values.  It should be noted that I'm not familiar with this `int arr[X][Y]` business when `X` and `Y` are not const (couldn't get it to compile), so I changed it to something I'm familiar with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int L,W,a,b,i,j,x,y,p,q,r,s;

int main()
{
    cin>>L>>W;
    int** peanut=new int*[L]; //a new row pointer for each column element
    for (i=0;i<L;i++){ 
     peanut[i]=new int[W]; //the actual row for each column element
        for (j=0;j<W;j++)
            cin>>peanut[i][j];
    }
    cin>>a>>b;

    //don't need to remember results; just compare maximum after each evaluation.
    //int sumArray[L-a+1][W-b+1];
    //memset(sumArray,0,(L-a+1)*(W-b+1)*sizeof(int));

    int max = 0;
    for (p=0;p<L-a+1;++p){
        for (q=0;q<W-b+1;++q){

           int sum=0;
           for (r=p;r<p+a;++r) //r<p ==> r<p+a, prefix increment is always better
               for (s=q;s<q+b;++s){ //s<q ==> s<q+b, prefix increment is always better
                   cout << "(" << r << "," << s << "," << peanut[r][s] << ") ";
                   sum+=peanut[r][s]; 
               }
           cout << sum << endl;
           if(sum>max) max=sum;

        }
    }

    /*  Merged in previous loop
    int max = 0;
    for (x=0;x<L-a+1;x++)
     for (y=0;y<W-b+1;y++) 
       if (sumArray[x][y]>max) max=sumArray[x][y];
    */

    cout << "Answer: " << max;

    //Since I'm in Visual Studio, I need to pause and see the result before quitting...
    int s;
    cin >> s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free allocated memory, or(better) use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I didn't want to include new headers, and the program ends when it is done with the array anyway.  If the program did other stuff afterwards, then a delete is certainly necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works pretty well. I got what is wrong. :)

Comment: @Aggieboy however when I submit the code to online judge, I got Time Limit Exceeded. How can I improve the algorithms?

Accepted (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5052kb)
Accepted (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4964kb)
Accepted (Time: 410ms, Memory: 7044kb)
Time Limit Exceeded (Time: 0ms, Memory: 0kb)
Time Limit Exceeded (Time: 0ms, Memory: 0kb)
Accepted (Time: 740ms, Memory: 6744kb)
Accepted (Time: 530ms, Memory: 8364kb)
Time Limit Exceeded (Time: 0ms, Memory: 0kb)
Time Limit Exceeded (Time: 0ms, Memory: 0kb)
Accepted (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5116kb)

Comment: Did you remove the `cin >> s;` at the end?  I only had that because I was in Visual Studio, and the console would close before I could see the output.  Additionally, removing extraneous `cout` commands would improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not index elements carefully to calculate the `sumArray`. I only changed two lines of your code to make it work.

```
for (r=0;r<a;r++)
  for (s=0;s<b;s++) sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[p+r][q+s];
```

The following is the full code. Please fix it if there are other problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int L,W,a,b,i,j,x,y,p,q,r,s;

int main()
{
    cin>>L>>W;
    int peanut[L][W];
    for (i=0;i<L;i++) 
     for (j=0;j<W;j++) 
       cin>>peanut[i][j];
    cin>>a>>b;

    int sumArray[L-a+1][W-b+1];
    memset(sumArray,0,(L-a+1)*(W-b+1)*sizeof(int));

    for (p=0;p<L-a+1;p++)
     for (q=0;q<W-b+1;q++) 
       {
        for (r=0;r<a;r++)
         for (s=0;s<b;s++) sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[p+r][q+s]; 
       }

    int max = 0;
    for (x=0;x<L-a+1;x++)
     for (y=0;y<W-b+1;y++) 
       if (sumArray[x][y]>max) max=sumArray[x][y];
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:

```
for (r=p;r<a;r++)
         for (s=q;s<b;s++) sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[r][s];
```

You are not iterating `a` and `b` times.  Change it to:

```
for (r=p;r<p+a;r++)
         for (s=q;s<q+b;s++) sumArray[p][q]+=peanut[r][s];
```